# How do I change the search frequency time limit?

Tags: search

EE 3.5.17

By default search frequency is set to 15 seconds. Is there a way to change that time limit?

I saw an old post from 2007 that said it was under Member Group settings, but I don't see anything like that.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in Member Group settings, you have to enable "Access search facility" first, that will reveal the frequency field. Default in EE5 is 10 seconds.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem.